# How to rotate to look at target

Tags: directx, rotation, vector, matrix, models

I have found other questions like this, but none seem to quite cover the situation I have.

I am using DirectX 11

I have an object that has:

- Position (vector)
- Rotation (quaternion)
- View angle (pitch, roll, yaw)

The view angle needs to be added to the rotation in order to know the true view rotation. You can think of view a head, and rotation as body.

I want to be able to turn the head so that it looks at a given point in space (vector)

The head needs to move slowly so I need to workout what way to turn and then move the head in that direction in small amounts. (pitch, yaw, roll) units

I have attempted to get this working but I don't even seem to be able to get close to what I need.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using DirectXTK or similar? Most math libraries have a Matrix::LookAt function which will generate what you're looking for.

Comment: I can create a look at matrix but that is not helping me as i need to know the difference so i can slowly turn in that direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)Convert your rotation angle to quaternion

2)Multiply this quaternion by your object's rotation quaternion

3)Use Spherical Linear Interpolation (SLERP) to interpolate between these two quaternions.

Comment: Note that quaternions turn out to LERP pretty well too (since their internal angle is half what we'd have from a corresponding rotation matrix, they're "more linear" in a sense). So unless you need precisely consistent speed of rotation, LERP+normalize can be a cheaper substitute for SLERP. Sometimes LERP is even desireable since it will give a slight ease-in and ease-out with peak speed in the middle of the rotation.